# How to verify TransparentUpgradeableProxy which is deployed using create2?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, verify, hardhat, etherscan

I have deployed an upgradable contract using a factory contract which its code is as fallows:

```
bytes memory bytecode = abi.encodePacked(
    type(TransparentUpgradeableProxy).creationCode,
    abi.encode(implementation, proxyAdmin, "")
);

assembly {
    contractAddress := create2(
        0,
        add(bytecode, 32),
        mload(bytecode),
        salt
    )
}
```

Everything is working fine. I did verify the implementation using hardhat but I can't verify the proxy itself. Hardhat gives me the following error:

> Failed to verify TransparentUpgradeableProxy contract at `addr`: Bytecode does not match with the current version of TransparentUpgradeableProxy in the Hardhat Upgrades plugin.

Any ideas?

I tried the hardhat CLI tool for verification